# updating user session from backend requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I have an app that stores the user data in the session.  Whenever I make changes to the user on the back end, I have to remember to also update the session data.  This is fine except when I make changes to the user that aren't initiated by his actions.  Then I don't have access to his request and therefore no access to his session.  This means that the user won't see the updates to his user record and even worse, if he makes a change to the user record before the session is updated he could wipe out changes made by the system.

My only solution is that I pull from the datastore instead of the session when saving changes.  This way I will never overwrite good data with outdated data.

Simple example if stackoverflow was coded like my site:

User reputation number is stored in the session, if someone upvotes one of their answers their reputation in the datastore increases, but this doesn't propagate to the session. The user could now update their about field and wipe out the reputation they just gained.

Hope this all makes sense, feel free to ask for any details I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this at the top of your JSP to identify the user on the session

```
if (session!=null && request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedin") != null) {
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("role").equals("STUDENT")) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        return;
    } 

}else{
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    return;
}%>
<% if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedin") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    return;
}
StudentDTO dto = (StudentDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

Then insert this code below in the JSP to post new data to the servlet

```
<form method="POST" action="EditUserServlet">

                    <div class="form-submit">   
                        My Information
                        <div class="submit-section">
                            <div class="form-row">

                                <div class="x">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= dto.getName()%>" name="name">
                                </div>

                                <div class="x">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="<%= dto.getEmail()%>" name="email">
                                </div>

                            <div class="form-group x">
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

In the EditUserServlet

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
         StudentDB db = new StudentDB();

        StudentDTO dto = db.getStudentByID(((StudentDTO) request.getSession().getAttribute("user")).getId());

        dto.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        dto.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));




        db.updateStudent(dto);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", dto);
```

In the StudentDB java file insert this to find the student by Id and then to update the student sql file

```
public StudentDTO getStudentByID(int id) {

    StudentDTO obj = null;
    String query = "Select * from students where id=?";
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1,id);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs != null) {
            if (rs.next()) {

                obj = new StudentDTO();
                obj.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                obj.setName(rs.getString(2));
                obj.setEmail(rs.getString(3));
                obj.setPassword(rs.getString(4));

} catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(StudentDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

public boolean updateStudent(StudentDTO obj)
{
    int affectedRows = 0;
    String query = "update `student` set name=? , email=lower(?)   where id=?";
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try {
         pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1,obj.getName());
        pst.setString(2,obj.getEmail());



        pst.setInt(10, obj.getId());
        System.out.println(pst);

        affectedRows = pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StudentDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return affectedRows > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store the data in session, IMO you can directly map it to the datastore that way you wont have the stale, old data and your datasource is updated every time you fetch the data

Comment: I have the user stored in the session for a few reasons, one is to make sure that the user has permission to do what they are trying to do.  I use the user in the session during changes so I don't have to make a call to the datastore since it is already available.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the gang of four observer pattern? 
Not following your use case fully either...

Comment: The observer pattern would work perfectly but how would I access the session when it needs to be updated.  Usually to update the session I do request.getSession().setAtribute("user", userObject); I can't do this if I'm in a request not generated by the user.